# How to Remove a control from another Sub than the one where the control was initially created in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have written some code to create a PictureBox every time the code runs, which works fine.

```
    Public Sub BtnHit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnHit.Click
            
            Dim PicBoxNewCard As New PictureBox
            PicBoxNewCard.Width = 114
            PicBoxNewCard.Height = 166
            PicBoxNewCard.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            DrawCard(PicBoxNewCard)
            Me.Controls.Add(PicBoxNewCard)
            PicBoxNewCard.Location = New Point((257 + (57 * DrawnCardCounter)), 349)
```

But I want to be able to delete these created PictureBoxes by pressing a button, which would be in a different sub to the one that creates the Boxes.

I have googled around and have found references to creating Classes, Panels etc and have not had any success. I have found the exact code that I need to make it work, (Me.Controls.Remove(PicBoxNewCard)) but it only seems to work when executed in the same Sub.

Comment: Give the picbox a name when you create it, and then find it and remove it by name.

Comment: What is the EXACT criteria by which you want to decide what to remove? Is it just going to be the last one (or last N) or are you going to want to remove one in the middle or something else? You need to be specific. The suggestion provided is to name the controls and remove by name but that's probably unnecessary as you can probably just use an index within the container. You need to provide ALL the relevant information though.

Comment: I would also suggest that you should probably be using either a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` as the container for the `PictureBoxes`. That would mean that there's no need to specify the `Location` and they would be the only controls in that container, making them easier to distinguish later.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Name` or `Tag` property and use that later when searching for the PictureBox to remove.

`PicBoxNewCard.Name = $"Card{DrawnCardCounter}"`

```
   Private Sub RemoveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveButton.Click
        RemoveCardPicBox(10)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveCardPicBox(CardNumber As Integer)

        Dim delpicBox As PictureBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).Where(Function(x) x.Name = $"Card{CardNumber}").FirstOrDefault
        If Not delpicBox Is Nothing Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(delpicBox)
        End If

    End Sub
```